# How to redirect a user to the blog after he creates the blog in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a blog project
I have added the create functionality to the blog after creating which he gets redirect to the homepage but I want the user to get redirected to the blog he just created

this is my view:

```
def createBlog(request):
form = BlogForm()

if request.method == "POST":
    form = BlogForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("blog")
        # the above redirect to the homepage
        # but I want it to redirect it to the blog page that he just created


context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "blog/blog_form.html", context)
```

and this is my url's page:

```
path("", views.blog, name="blog"),
path("blog/<str:pk>/", views.blog, name="blogs"),
path("create-blog", views.createBlog, name="create-blog")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form.save()` returns the instance that just created and thus you will get the PK value of the instance from that.

```py
def createBlog(request):
    form = BlogForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            blog_instance = form.save()
            return redirect("blogs", pk=blog_instance.pk)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "blog/blog_form.html", context)
```